# CakePHP paginate 'virtual' field

Tags: cakephp, virtual, field, pagination

I have a model **Item** with its corresponding table **items** and fields (field1, field2, etc).

I have another model, **Comment**, whith also its table and fields. One of the fields is **item_rating**, where users enter a number between 0 to 10 to rate the item.

Both models are related like **Item** *hasMany* **Comment**, and **Comment** *belongsTo* **Item**.

When paginating the **Item** model in the view, I would like to add the field **item_rating** along with its own fields, so users can see an average rating of the item and be able to sort by **item_rating**, apart from all the other fields that belong directly to **Item**.

To do this, I figure I would need 2 things:

- Be able to create the **item_rating** field *on the fly* with the average of all its ratings
- Be able to add that field to the pagination so users can see it and sort by it

Is this possible? Can anyone point me to the right direction of how to accomplish it? Or should I just add a *real* **item_rating** field to my **items** table and update the average everytime a new rating is added by a user?

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the best way is to use a real field in your parent table. Here is a behavior which you can use for your purpose:[Aggregatable behaviour](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/vincentm8/2010/08/23/aggregatecache-behavior)

Edit:

You can do such functionality by your own. Just create a field in your parent table which will hold the average rating. Then on afterSave() in your Rating model, add functionality that fills that field in the parent table with the average value.

Comment: hey thanks for the link. However, I get the typical error "headers already sent by.... aggregate_cache.php". That's the file in the example, so I don't know if there might be something wrong with it, I'm using it as it's there. Do you know what can be wrong? Or do you have an alternative behavior or method?

Comment: Ok I just fixed that, there was a problem with copying the code from directly from the web page. I copied it first to the notepad and then to my editor and the error is gone. However, I can't seem to make it do what's supposed to do...

Comment: It's not my code, and I don't know details. See my revised answer for more details

Comment: I got it to work! The problem was that I had not realized that it only works for **NEW** entries (*comments*) in this case. Whatever was previously there (in the DB) it won't be paginated/sorted correctly. Thanks for the tip!